# Reuse a View Controller by incrementing a NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

**Edit:** I solved my own problem by using 2 view controllers instead of 1, and am using the same method, but now passing the value from one to another, back and forth.

Let's say I have a View Controller called **ViewController** and have declared a **NSInteger** called **section** in the header file of **ViewController**.

Now, I have a button on the view controller, and every time this button is pressed I increment the value of **section** and push **ViewController**:

```
- (IBAction)nextAction:(id)sender
{
     ViewController *viewCon = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
     viewCon.section = viewCon.section + 1;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCon animated:YES];
}
```

The problem I am having is when I press this button, **section** increments from 0 to 1, and does not increment any higher. What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

***The problem I am having is when I press this button, section increments from 0 to 1, and does not increment any higher. What do you suggest?***

You are creating your view controller as a local variable so, when it is popped of the navigation controller stack it is being de-allocated, your view controller object no longer exists!

You should make you view controller a instance variable of the class that contains your nextAction method and in the nextAction method you should check to see if your view controller is nil, and if it is initialize you instance variable. After you have done this you should increment your section counter.